# AS3 get smoother image rotation

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a timer that rotates image for 2 degrees every 10 ms 1000 times. It rotates well, but sometimes (not always) I see some stuttering for just a tiny bit of time, it's not big but it is noticeable. How can I change my code to prevent that? Is there faster and better way than using "mc.rotationZ"? It might be my timer with 10ms time cycle, that causes problem?

EDIT: If timer is a problem, what are alternatives for it?

```
startbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,okreni1);
var tajmer:Timer=new Timer(10,1000);
tajmer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,okreni2);

function okreni1(e:Event){
    startbtn.mouseEnabled = false;
    tajmer.start();
}

function okreni2(e:Event){
    wheel.wrotate.rotationZ += 2;

    if(tajmer.currentCount == 1000){
        trace("tajmer se zavrsio");
        startbtn.mouseEnabled = true;
        tajmer.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting `myBitmap.pixelSnapping = PixelSnapping.NEVER` ? What's your framerate?

Comment: I haven't used bitmap, I used png image. Should I create bitmap or vector for better performance?

Comment: performance is not your issue here, see botmasters comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Could be performance (UPDATE: from your comments I'm going to say this is unlikely)
2. Make sure if using an image, that bitmap smoothing is enabled on it and pixel snapping is off.
3. Make sure you're publishing with GPU acceleration.
4. Make sure you're not scaling the parent(s) of `wrotate` a huge amount. You can get into jerky motion when things get scaled up really far.

It's likely that the problem would be resolved if you updated the object every frame instead of on a timer event.  Though it's best to do this even if it's not your main problem.

at 10ms, you're actually making changes faster than 60fps (which is 16.6ms).  At flash pro's default 24fps (41.6ms) that's 4 timer ticks before your changes are drawn.  Plus, timer's can't reliably sync to the frame rate even if you did the math right.

I've modified your code so that the timer only has one tick that spans the entire duration of the rotation.  An enter frame listener is what handles the rotation so that it's synced with the actual frame rate of the application.

```
startbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,okreni1);
var tajmer:Timer=new Timer(10000, 1); //just fire it once 
tajmer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,okreni2);

function okreni1(e:Event){
    startbtn.mouseEnabled = false;
    tajmer.reset();
    tajmer.start();
    wheel.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateWheel,false,0,true); //run updateWheel every frame
}

function okreni2(e:Event){
    wheel.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateWheel,false);  //remove the listener so it stops rotating
    trace("tajmer se zavrsio");
    startbtn.mouseEnabled = true;
}
function updateWheel(e:Event){
    wheel.wrotate.rotationZ += 2;
}
```

---

As an aside, this scenario is a perfect candidate for **Tweening**.  If you wanted to use the ever popular [TweenLite](http://greensock.com/gsap-as),  your code would look like this:

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.Linear;
import com.greensock.easing.Quad;

startbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,okreni1);

function okreni1(e:Event){
    startbtn.mouseEnabled = false;

    //this tells wheel.wrotate to animate over 10 seconds from the current rotationZ value to an additional 20000.  Ease none means have the velocity constant the whole time. 
    //alternatively you could use a different ease, like Quad.easeInOut if you want a nice smooth start and stop
    TweenLite.to(wheel.wrotate, 10, { rotationZ: wheel.wrotate.rotationZ + 20000, ease: Linear.easeNone, onComplete: okreni2 });
}

function okreni2(e:Event){
    startbtn.mouseEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: It's maybe a little better, but I can still sometimes see some little stuttering. Thanks!

Comment: What's your frame rate?  Are you sure it's not performance related?

Comment: I set FPS to 30, I'm testing swf on my PC (amd fx-8350 processor) and on old iPhone (AIR app), and I get same effect on both.

Comment: I just found about TweenMax and I am testing it. Can you tell me what that number (after movieclip name, in your example is "10") means/represents?

Comment: That would be the duration of the tween in seconds.

Comment: So, main goal should be to sync rotation intervals with FPS and animation should be smooth then?

Comment: It will be smoother than it otherwise would have been animating via a timer.  As I try to detail in my answer, there are numerous things that could cause something to not look smooth while animating.

Comment: Which method is better: mc.rotation+=value or TweenMax.to(...)?

Comment: There is a very small amount of overhead with TweenMax. So in that sense it's less desirable, but the overhead is so negligible that unless you're doing banner ads (and even then) it won't matter in any noticeable way.  TweenMax is less code for you to write, and has lots of optimizations (like syncing to the frame rate automatically). It's a very convenient library especially if you want to use easing and tween multiple properties of the same object.  SO basically, using a tweening engine is better for you the developer, and will produce the same result.

Comment: Did you get it to play satisfactorily smoothly?

Comment: It's close, i'm using code below and it is fluid 80% of time, it still sometimes stutters for a bit, but it is much better than before. Does tweenmax fully automatically syncs to fps or I need to specify that function?

CODE:

startbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, okreni);

function okreni(e:Event):void{
TweenMax.to(wheel.wrotate, 9, {rotationZ:"1080",ease: Quad.easeOut});
}

Comment: TweenMax syncs to fps automatically.  I think you will want to take your `1080` out of quotes as it should be a number not a string (tweenMax is likely converting it for you).

Comment: Here is my FLA file, try it for yourself and tell me if you see even little stutter. FOr me it stutters when slowing down. If you have something in mind that can fix it, try. Thank you. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2kjd7ayj3pulyv/okretanje2.fla?dl=0

Comment: Quite a few misguided statements here like "actually drawing changes faster than" Timer of course don't force a redraw unless you tell them to with updateAfterEvent() if you don't then whatever is going on in the listener will be drawn like everything else on the next screen update. Next a PNG and a bitmap is the same thing. Next bitmap are not good candidate for rotation, this is stated many times in the AS3 docs.

Comment: @BotMaster - A "misguided" comment.  No where do I say a timer forces a redraw, infact I'm saying the opposite.   And no where do I mention PNGs...

Comment: @exiibeat -  I opened up your .fla.   You don't have pixel smoothing turned on.  Turning it on (you can do so in the library by right clicking the image and going to properties) and also turning on GPU acceleration in the publish settings made it run nice and smooth

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I tested my FLA (swf) on school's old pc with 1 cpu core and integrated gpu, and rotation(animation) worked flawlessly. But I think maybe the problem is in my flash professional or flash player. I will reinstall and update my software. Thank you @LMDS very much for all help.